# Java access to internet searches?

Tags: java, search

I was wondering how it is possible to have a java program search Google. For example, I want to write to program where the user can input the name of a resteraunt and then have the program search the name on Google, find the address, and then return it. I do think it is possible, because I know programs that are web crawlers. But I was wondering how to learn the specific code or way to write that, because I'm not at all certain where to start.

Thank you.

Comment: start here: [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). this class will allow you to send an HTTP request to the site, and get the result page contents

Comment: Also, it may be worth looking into cURL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL .

Comment: Google does not allow automated requests for you to scrape. It's against their ToS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in web crawlers, here is an article that details a Java solution.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ThirdParty/WebCrawler/

Answer (score 1):

Google has deprecated their search API in favor of a more general Custom Search API:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Using your own API key you would do something like the following:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures
```

That will return [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) that you can parse to display the data any way you want.

Here's good info on getting started: http://blog.lux-medien.com/2011/08/google-custom-search-java-implementation/